# Laravel 9 dropzone "app\models\examplemodel not found" error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I'm asking you because I can't solve my problem.

file upload no problem but db insert is error

my blade code

```
<form action="{{ route('admin_multiupload_store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="image-upload">
                @csrf
                
                <input type="hidden" name="type" value="{{ $type }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $id }}">
</form>
```

my javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
    new Dropzone("#image-upload", {
        maxFilesize:12,
        acceptedFiles:".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.svg",
        addRemoveLink:true,
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(file, response){
            Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'İşlem Başarılı...',
            text: '{!! session()->get('success') !!}'
        });
        },
        error: function(file, response){
            return false;
        }
    })
</script>
```

my controller code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Models\MultiImageModel;

class MultiImageController extends Controller
{
    public function index($type, $id) {
        return view('admin.multiupload', compact('type','id'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $imageName = time().rand(1,1000).'.'.$image->extension();
        $image->move(public_path('uploads/'),$imageName);

        $image_data = new MultiImageModel();
        var_dump($image_data);
        $image_data->upload_type = $request->type;  
        $image_data->upload_id = $request->id;
        $image_data->upload_filephp = $imageName;  
        $image_data->save();

        return response()->json(['success'=> $imageName]);
    }
}
```

model code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MultiImageModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'multi_image_models';
    use HasFactory;
}
```

the error i encountered
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvr8h.png)

Waiting for your replies, thanks :)

uploading the file to the directory and saving it to the database, but I can't save it to the database. only file upload is successful

Comment: It seems your model cannot be found. Show your model please.

Comment: @cengsemihsahin I added the model code

Comment: Can you try to change this line: `use app\Models\MultiImageModel;` to `use App\Models\MultiImageModel;` Maybe just need upper char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement where you import the model class, capital letter "App" in the controller